# SFTP with pysftp and paramiko on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk EB known_hosts

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, paramiko, pysftp

So I am building a Flask micro-service to connect up two API's. One of the API's requires all communication to be via SFTP to move XML files around (yay! ).

On Windows, I was able to get this working after quite a lot of fiddling. The trouble had been that unless I had logged in using FileZilla and accepted the host key, pysftp/paramiko wouldn't connect.

To solve that I wrote a function to check the known_hosts file in "C:/Users/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts" and if the key is missing for the site, I use paramiko to get the key.

```
from pysftp import known_hosts
import paramiko


def check_for_host_key(hostname):
    """
    Checks for host key in known_hosts file
    If it is not found, it will get it and add it to known_hosts
    """
    
    KNOWN_HOSTS = known_hosts()  # this fn returns a string looking like 'C:/Users/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts' but is OS agnostic and works fine under Linux.

    if os.path.isfile(KNOWN_HOSTS):
        pass
    else:
        # if known_hosts doesn't exist, create it in default directory
        try:
            open(KNOWN_HOSTS, 'a+').close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            KNOWN_HOSTS = "/home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts"
            open(KNOWN_HOSTS, 'a+').close()

    # check if host key is present
    if open(KNOWN_HOSTS, 'r').read().find(hostname) != -1:
        return

    # if not get it...
    print(f"host key not found in known_hosts({KNOWN_HOSTS})\ngetting host key")
    transport = paramiko.Transport(hostname)
    transport.connect()
    key = transport.get_remote_server_key()
    transport.close()

    # and save it
    hostfile = paramiko.HostKeys(filename=KNOWN_HOSTS)
    hostfile.add(hostname=hostname, key=key, keytype=key.get_name())
    hostfile.save(filename=KNOWN_HOSTS)
    print(f"host key saved to known_hosts({KNOWN_HOSTS})")
    return
```

The above function works really well on Windows and I expected it to work fine when deployed to AWS on a LInux server as the code I initially saw to modify the known_hosts file was written for Linux (if memory serves...). But when I deployed to Elastic Beanstalk (using EB CLI) I keep getting 502 errors.

Checking the AWS logs I can see a specific error coming up when the check_for_host_key function is called during boot (hence the 502's):

```
Jul 15 21:15:21 ip-172-31-19-61 web: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul 15 21:15:21 ip-172-31-19-61 web: File "/var/app/current/app/config.py", line 16, in Config
Jul 15 21:15:21 ip-172-31-19-61 web: open(KNOWN_HOSTS, 'a+').close()
Jul 15 21:15:21 ip-172-31-19-61 web: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/webapp/.ssh/known_hosts'
.......
Jul 15 21:15:21 ip-172-31-19-61 web: open(KNOWN_HOSTS, 'a+').close()
Jul 15 21:15:21 ip-172-31-19-61 web: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts'
```

The first error is the real one, `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/webapp/.ssh/known_hosts'`.

Why can't my python application find the relevant directory? The line of code in question will actually create the file if it is missing on Windows, and my understanding is it should do the same on Linux.

The 2nd error is me trying to troubleshoot and use a different users home folder, but this fails due to a permission error.

Next I used `eb ssh` in Powershell Terminal to SSH into my application instance (this automatically logged me in as ec2-user) and I started to browse the folder structure. What I found was that I could not enter the /home/webapp/ directory at all, again due to a permission error. The exact error was:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-61 home]$ cd ./webapp
-bash: cd: ./webapp: Permission denied
```

As far as I can tell, the only way for me to successfully initiate a SFTP connection from AWS will involve having the host key stored in `known_hosts` (I am aware of the MITM implications of doing this automatically, but that isn't a concern here) but that doesn't seem to be an option, whether via SSH or from the application instance.

Is it possible I need to do something with IAM roles? I think that would explain the SSH profile not being able to browse the `/home/webapp/` directory, but I'm not sure how that will help the application itself.

All in I am completely lost. I am new to AWS and I'm not exactly a Linux expert either so I really would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be some confusion on the users and folders.

You application executes under `webapp` user. So your application won't be able  to modify any folders belonging to `ec2-user` as you are attempting:

```
KNOWN_HOSTS = "/home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts"
```

Creating such `/home/webapp/.ssh/known_hosts` file will also fail, because by default folder `/home/webapp/.ssh/` **does not exist**. Have to create it first before you can add `known_hosts` into it.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! I thought that the folder thing might be to do with wrong users etc. In the end you were absolutely right, the ./ssh/ directory didn't exist, and I had to change some code to add it. Thanks!

Comment: @ShmuliMargulies No problem. Glad it worked out :-)